# Target only last level element with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, attributes, tabindex

I'm trying to apply `tabindex="0"` to a bunch of elements that :

- have text in it
- does't still have a `tabindex`.

This is my code :

```
$(elems).not("[disabled]").each(function() {
    let n = $(this).attr('tabindex');
    if ((typeof n == typeof undefined || n == !1) && ($(this).text().trim().length)) {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', '0')
    }
});
```

**The user is blind and travels through the page with `TAB`, the text is read with *vocal synthesis***.

**1#** This case is okay

```
    <div>Example text</div>
--> <div tabindex="0">Example text</div>
```

**2#** This case is problematic (first focus on `div` then focus on `p` so "Example text" read twice)

```
    <div>
        <p>Example text</p>
    </div>

--> <div tabindex="0">
        <p tabindex="0">Example text</p>
    </div>
```

**2#** This case is more problematic ("First text Second text" read then "Second text" again)

```
<div tabindex="0">First text
    <p tabindex="0">Second text</p>
</div>
```

I want "First text" to be read first, then "Second text".

I have a lot of solutions but heavy and inelegants. If you have a simple one, thank you in advance !

Basicaly, I want to apply a tabindex only on the TAG with text, except if it's text formating tab (b,i,u,strong...). Example:

```
<div>
  <p tabindex="0">This is <b>great</b> !</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The first argument to the `each()` handler function is the index of the element. Assign that as the value of the `tabindex` attribute. Better yet - put this directly in your HTML source in case the screenreader in use doesn't interpret JS updates to the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi and thx ! We assume the user has no screenreader. For a public access computer, a library for example. So I try to simulate a screenreader.

Comment: It sounds like you have already solved this problem, but you haven't described the issue with your solution. So.... we don't have anything to work with in your question. You may want to check out Code Review, though you'll probably need to [re-word your question a bit to fit their format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As-is, this question is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (all answers are equally valid and there is no actual problem to be solved).

Comment: @JDB I understand but if I wrote the question this way and if I'm asking, it's because the solution does not jump at me. My code is not doing what I want and I have no solutions right now, that's why I'm asking for help. If I had a solution, I'll would apply it :) I certainly don't have the global vision  need for my work right now

Comment: Oh, ok... then why did you say "*I have a lot of solutions but heavy and inelegants*"? Is that inaccurate? Also, providing examples of those solutions would be enormously helpful in understanding how you're approaching this issue and which corrections may be most helpful to you.

Comment: @JDB You're right ! But I know my javascript knowledge is not exhaustive and I could have missed some simple JS / jQuery functions that would do the job easily. I think `$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text()` is inelegant for example, leaving me to think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can read of your question, it sounds like the main issue is that jQuery's `text()` function is returning too much text in cases where an element has child elements. You particularly want to be able to pick out the "foo" and "baz" separate from the "bar" in the following example:

```
<div>foo<p>bar</p>baz</div>
```

If that's the case, then you need to stop working with "elements" and start working with [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). Nodes are much more fine-grained and give you greater insight into what the DOM actually looks like. For example, the above will be parse into roughly the following node tree:

```
element: div
    text: "foo"
    element: p
        text: "bar"
    text: "baz"
```

Nodes are more difficult to work with, because there are so many more of them of different types with different features. That's a cost you generally have to take on when you need more control, though.

Here's one example of how you might accomplish your goal, but you'll probably need to adapt it to your specific needs.

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');

processChildNodes( root );

// Log the resulting HTML to the console
// so that we can see the tab index attribute:
console.log( root.innerHTML );

function processChildNodes(parent){
  var child;
  // Get either the first child of the parent or the next sibling of
  // the current child.
  // If we don't have any children or we run out of siblings, then
  // we're done here.
  while ( child = child ? child.nextSibling : parent.firstChild ){
    // If the node is disabled, then skip it.
    // Maybe this should be data-disabled?
    switch (child.nodeType){
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        // If the current node is an element, then set the tabIndex
        // and process the children.
        if ( !child.hasAttribute('disabled') ){
          child.setAttribute( 'tabindex',  '0' );
          processChildNodes( child );
        }
        break;
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // If the current node is text, then "read" the text.
        // You don't have an example of how this is supposed to work,
        // so I'll just print it to the console.
        var text = (child.nodeValue || "").trim();
        if (text.length > 0) console.log( 'reading: ' + text );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>Example text 1</div>

  <div>
    <p>Example text 2</p>
  </div>

  <div>
      First text
      <p>Second text</p>
      Third text
      <p>
        Fourth text
        <span>Fifth text</span>
      </p>
      <p disabled>
        Skip this one.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx !  it works great ! But it gives `tabindex` to all elements, so all of them are tabbable, what I do not want. 'Cause now I don't know how to target a peculiar node to be read :/ But you teached me how to work with nodes so I have a new way to explore and find a solution :)